# Get File by path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found I could get a file by:

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Some Directory");
```

The file is one contained within this collection;

However is there a method to get a single file by passing the file path tothis method?

Comment: I'm sorry , I dont know if you had got a single file , Why do you use the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alot of ways to directly access a file by path. Here are a few:

```
        string path = // path string here

        File.ReadAllText(path);

        File.OpenRead(path);

        File.OpenWrite(path);
```

Essentially everything the 'File' class does is related to a single file. Its a static class in the System.IO namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx

System.IO.File.Open